# Small dialog in chrome

Tags: sitecore-client

I'm using Sitecore for a few months and in most of the cases that Sitecore shows me a dialog, the dialog is really small and I have to change the height through the developer tools.

This is an image to show how I see the dialogs.
[image]

In Microsoft Edge, the dialog is shown with the right size and in a coworker computer, the dialog on Chrome is shown with the right size too.

My specification:

- Windows 10 installed on Bootcamp partition of a Macbook Pro Retina
  display
- Chrome version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
- Display Settings: Macbook screen: 2880x1800 (at 200%), Second
  Monitor: 1366x768 (at 100%). Must say that in both monitors the problem is the same.
- In Chrome incognito also happens.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: What version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: I've used 7.1 and now i'm using 8.2 with the same result on both versions

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console window?

Comment: I see an error when i navigate thru the items `X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside <meta>.` but no error is shown when the dialog opens.

Comment: Is this on an upgraded Sitecore instance or a clean install? Also, does this also happen in other browsers or just Chrome?

Comment: This happens in Chrome only (i've tested on Edge with no problem) and happens on every instance. No instance has been upgraded, all are clean installations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox and IE or Edge are known to be most stable for Sitecore administration, that is, the Sitecore back office.

I have saw this at the following link: [Practical Sitecore 8 Configuration and Strategy: A User Guide for Sitecore](https://books.google.mu/books?id=ZqIvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=sitecore%20most%20stable%20administration%20browser&source=bl&ots=VlRfL4TlAE&sig=8I65ztOvdj2tvHY76rA2p3bFHCs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif1cXb3MTSAhVJUBQKHYWvCXMQ6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q=sitecore%20most%20stable%20administration%20browser&f=false)

Moreover, some users experienced Modal box issues on Chrome. A statement from Sitecore knowledge base:

> Sitecore versions prior to Sitecore CMS 7.1 might be not working properly in Chrome 37 and later due to the deprecated support for modal dialog boxes in these versions of Chrome.

Source: [Sitecore knowledge base](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/581527)

But it was supposed to be fixed in latest Sitecore versions. It might be related to a JavaScript issue since I have seen in some Sitecore JS files, it caters for different browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome).

**UPDATE**

Though, it might also due to your display resolution. The JavaScript function will take into account the `window` which is then used to calculate the dialog width and height.

Comment: That could be the issue i'm facing... i will switch to firefox to work with sitecore then... i will put this as an answer. (i don't think it's a display resolution problem because in both monitors the problem is the same).

Comment: @Phoenix_uy, you may raise a Sitecore Support ticket so that Sitecore may provide more information